# Op-Amp and foldback limiting of voltage power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am new in forum.

1. Can an opamp which drives a small load and whose output current exceeds the maximum output current of the opamp cause a foldback limiting of the power supply?
2. If I use a class ab push-pull stage to boost the output current and the current Ic for a voltage Vce does not respect the SOA (safe operating area) of the transistors, can I have also foldack limiting from the power supply?

I have been working on a circuit and every time I exceed a current amplitude level, I have a foldback limiting from the power supply.I verified and I don't have voltage saturation of my opamp and the input respect the common mode range input given in the datasheet.

Comment: The power supply should have a current limit much higher than the OpAmp, so, unless there is a short circuit rather than an overcurrent, the supply should not foldback.

Comment: Thanks Andrea,
But when you talk about the current limit of the power supply must be greater than the current of the Aop, is it rms value or peak value? I must adjust the current limit of the power voltage compared to the peak or rms value of the amplifier ?

Comment: Of course peak current. I mean: you have an OpAmp with let's say 50 mA max peak output, and the dc/dc converter or voltage regulator is rated min 100 mA, not to say more. This is why I do not think that an overcurrent (e.g. 50mA+10%) can cause foldback or protection of any kind. Maybe a momentary short circuit : in this case big thank you to the power supply, and luckily nothing burned. If instead you use a lab pow supply trimmed exactly to the current you need + epsilon, that's different pair of shoes.

Comment: Usually the power supply has more current availability of the opamp (there are amps giving out some ampere, however). Unless you have really big bypass capacitors (for handling the transients), the supply will handle the peak current, of course.

Comment: thank's,
I check my card once again for possible short circuit.